# Alternatives of javax.comm

Tags: java, java-native-interface, hardware, javax.comm

Hi all i want to control a parallel port through java code, when i googled i found a few packages like javax.comm , RXTX, SerialIO.com (website) etc. Currently i have written a native code(in C) for port communication.And let JNI do the communication between C - java.
I have seen a few questions on stackoverflow also, but i wasnot able to find any comparision between the packages/techniques.So according to your experience and opinion which option is better and why? 

I am using windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

i have only used rxtx on windoze xp for an [hdmi switch](http://hallresearch.com/page/SW-HDMI-4). it seemed to work fine.